# One scroll bar for 2 separate divs

Tags: php, html, css, sidebar

I have two DIV's that are side by side. One div is my side bar (Left Of Screen), the other div is my main content (Right Of Screen).

What I'm looking for:
What I want is one visable scroll bar to the far right of the screen. I would like that scrol bar to scroll both left and right div's.

My Problem:
Currently my left sidebar has a tree menu. When I expand my tree menu, I have no scroll bar to scroll down through the side bar content that was expanded. I'm able to add a scroll bar to my side bar, but that looks very ugly. I just want 1 scroll bar on the far right that handles both div's.
Can someone help me on this one?

My `index.php` file

```php
<?php

include 'sidebar.php';
include 'main_body.php';

?>
```

My `sidebar.php`

```php
<?php

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1_3_2.js"></script>';

    include 'function/functions.php';
    // Establish a connection to our database
    db_connect();

    echo'
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".content").hide();
      //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
      jQuery(".heading").click(function()
      {
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
      });
    });
    </script>
    ';

    echo'<div class="sidebar">';

    // Side Bar Start
    echo '
    <img src="images/hdc_logo.png">
    <br>
    <br>

    <p class="heading"><strong>CUSTOMER</strong></p>
    <div class="content">';

    //Display all customers from database
    query_all_customers();

    echo '</div>
    <p class="heading"><strong>CABINET</strong></p>
    <div class="content">';

    // Display all cabinets from database
    query_all_cabinets();
    echo'</div>
    </div>';

    ?>
```

My main content area

```php
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    echo '<div class="main">';

    echo'
    <br>
    <br>
    Some data can go here
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    Some data can go here
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    Some data can go here
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    Some data can go here
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    and here
    <br>
    <br>
    and here';
    ?>
```

My `.css` file

```css
.sidebar {
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#54524F;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
.main {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.heading {
    margin: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#000000;
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#submit {
    width:185px;
    background-color: black;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Oswald';
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}
#submit:hover {
    border: none;
    background:#FF9933;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color:#D4D4D4;
}
.container0 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrJDE/)

Comment: Show us your `html` & `css`, not your `php` ;)

Comment: Could you provide some more of the code?

Comment: We are not a magician or a special people to find your code in sidebar.php and that other thing..!

Comment: I've updated this post with my code.

Comment: It's `position:fixed;` that's screwing you.

Comment: @DiMono - What do you suggest?

Comment: ...remove `position:fixed;`?

Comment: Removing it didnt Help. Here's the thing, if there isnt' enough content in length in the main div (right side) for scrolling, there is no scroll bar visible. Even if the Left side bar has content that exceeds the length of the screen, I still do not see a visible scroll bar.

Comment: Further more, removing the position:fixed attribute in the css pushed the data in the main content down to the bottom of the screen. Looks out of wack.

Comment: actually, your suggestion may work if I can get the main div content to show at the top of the page instead of being pushed down to the bottom of the screen. I do see a scroll bar now after removing that attribute, but I can't tell if it's working or if it's due to the data being pushed down and presented at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css, set position of the sidebar to relative and set float to left, like this:

```
.sidebar {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#54524F;
    float:left
}
```

the updated version of your jsfiddle to show you that it works :) http://jsfiddle.net/BrJDE/3/

because you dont want to have the scrollbar at the side of the page, i made some more examples for you. tell me if they are what you want, if its not, i would love to help you again.

both of these examples use 2 additional divs compared to the content you provided. these will make that you can position the scrollbar inside those div's instead of at the side of the browser. if you need me to explain the changes i made, just tell me.

scrollbar inside the page:
http://jsfiddle.net/BrJDE/6/

scrollbar inside the page at the left side of the scrolling div:
http://jsfiddle.net/BrJDE/5/

Comment: I changed the sidebar css to match yours and I cannot get the scroll bar to show. I expanded the contents in the sidebar but there is not scrollbar. How did you get the scrollbar on the sidebar to show?

Comment: it should appear automaticly when you set the sidebar to position:relative and the sidebar becomes larger than the screen

Comment: Yep, had to flush cache. I guess this will work for now, until I can figure something else out. Having a scroll bar on the sidebar looks so old school to me...lol. At least it only appears when needed and not static. Thanks for all your help man. I guess I can move foward again. Your the man!

Comment: I can try to make a better solution, but it Will take a few hours becouse im on my way home from work right now.

Comment: Roger that. I'll keep my eye on this post.

Comment: Roger that, Thanks man. I'll play around with these and see. Thanks again!